# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'total_faci.Branch' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select * from `dashboard_datas`)

Tags: laravel

Hi im trying to retrieve the data on the sql view that i create 
i already edit the config file and change the strict => true into strict => false. if you know how to retrieve the data please help me really appreciate the help..

```
 $datas = DB::table('dashboard_datas')->get();
  return $datas;
```

Comment: Can you do `php artisan config:clear`? Also whats `dashboard_datas`? is it a view or a table? Also are yo sure this query is causing the issue or there is any other query involving `total_fci` table on the same page?

Comment: your query seems ok..as @MihirBhende said the issue somewhere else